# How to add zIndex in typescript / MUI

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, material-ui, styled-components

**Hi so I think Vercel is overriding my css it's working perfectly on local but some styles are not applying once on Vercel Env. So the background color worked when I applied !important. I'm now trying to apply the same on zIndex but its not working. Please assist  **

Type '`${number} !important`' is not assignable to type 'ZIndexProperty | PropsFunc<(value: JSSFontface, index: number, array: JSSFontface[]) => unknown, ZIndexProperty>'.
Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'ZIndexProperty | PropsFunc<(value: JSSFontface, index: number, array: JSSFontface[]) => unknown, ZIndexProperty>'.
Type '`${number} !important`' is not assignable to type '"auto"'.
Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"auto"'

````
const drawerWidth = 280;
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme: Theme) =>
  createStyles({
    root: {
      display: 'flex'
    },
    appBar: {
      zIndex: `${theme.zIndex.drawer + 1} !important`,
      transition: theme.transitions.create(['width', 'margin'], {
        easing: theme.transitions.easing.sharp,
        duration: theme.transitions.duration.leavingScreen
      }),
      backgroundColor: `${theme.palette.secondary.contrastText} !important`,
      height: 80,
      paddingTop: theme.spacing(2),
      display: 'flex',
      flexDirection: 'column',
      justifyContent: 'center'
    },```
````

Answer (score 1):

Why use !Important ?
Try to ask like this:

```
import {makeStyles, Theme} from '@material-ui/core';

export const useStyles = makeStyles((theme: Theme) => ({
  appbar: {
    zIndex: theme.zIndex.drawer + 1,
  },
}));
```

and use:

```
import { AppBar as MuiAppBar, Toolbar } from '@material-ui/core';
import { useStyles } from "./Appbar.styles";

const Appbar: FC = ({ children }) => {

  const classes = useStyles()

  return (
    <MuiAppBar position="fixed" className={classes.appbar}>
      <Toolbar>{children}</Toolbar>
    </MuiAppBar>
  );
};


export default Appbar;
```

Comment: type zIndex  =  Globals | "auto" | number, zIndex cannot accept string

Comment: Styles in makestyles above the default styles of material-ui